# log sampling distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

I am using a python parameter optimization library

https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/documentation/hyperparameters/

And here were have the option to define a sampling distribution for various parameters. As i understand this essentially means that we will randomly draw a parameter from one end of the bounds more than the other end. However i'm not sure what this favors. For plain logarithmic sampling, does this mean that we will sample smaller values more often than larger values? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using logarithmic sampling, it means that you are sampling uniformly on the log-transformed interval.

Here are 20 random values logarithmically sampled between 0 and 10: 
[image]

And here are those same values plotted on the log-axis:
[image]

So, quick answer, **small values are sampled more frequently!**